# Eclipse linux windows charset

Tags: android, eclipse, character-encoding

When I compile my project (it's in russian) in linux eclipse, everything looks good. But when I compile it in windows eclipse, symbols are not shown properly, what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check (in file/folder properties in eclipse) if the encoding is set to `UTF-8` for your resources files. I also develop project in Russian and use both platforms without any issues.

Comment: OK! it did help. I've changed CHARSET properties for the current project.